# Rename checkboxes in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

The following code adds checkboxes to a row of cells and names them using the cell address

```
Dim CBX As CheckBox
    For x = 3 To 9
        With Cells(LastRow + 1, x)
            Set CBX = .Parent.CheckBoxes.add _
                        (Top:=.Top, _
                         Left:=.Left, _
                         Width:=.Width, _
                         Height:=.Height)
            CBX.Name = "ChkBox_" & .Address(0, 0)
            CBX.Caption = ""
            CBX.Value = xlOff
        End With
    Next x
```

I need the user to be able to delete a row at any given time and the checkboxes that reside within it - hence the code below

```
Dim strAgent As Long
strAgent = InputBox("Please enter the row number you wish to delete. WARNING - THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE")

Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_C" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_D" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_E" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_F" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_G" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_H" & strAgent).Delete
Sheets(1).Shapes("ChkBox_I" & strAgent).Delete

Rows(strAgent).EntireRow.Delete
```

The problem I have it that once the user deletes the row and everything gets moved, the checkbox names no longer correctly reference the cell they're located in.

How can I iterate through all of the checkboxes in these cells and rename them based on their new location?

Note: I am using form control checkboxes rather than activex checkboxes (i.e. shapes).

Comment: Shapes have a `TopLeftCell` property which corresponds to the cell under the top-left corner of the shape.  As long as your checkboxes don't drift out of their respective cells that should allow you to rename them (however, that means you can just use the TopLeftCell property instead of naming them in the first place)